# Flip order of std::pair

Tags: c++, std

How can I flip the order of `std::pair`?
Is there an in-build command or I need to create a new pair.

Currently I am doing this by creating a new pair.

```
std::pair el_ids(0,1);
el_ids = std::make_pair(el_ids.second, el_ids.first);
```

Comment: `std::swap` if inplace.

Comment: Are the first and second types actually the same, and you want the same `pair<T,T>` object with the values swapped? Or do you want to convert `pair<T,U>` to `pair<U,T>` as well?

Comment: Are the two element types identical?

Comment: Yes identifical, either two integers, or two std::array<std::vector<Point>,2>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as both types of the pair are the same you can just swap them (like @273k has pointed out in the comments), e.g.:

[godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/MPnvabdaW)

```cpp
std::pair p = {1, 2};
std::swap(p.first, p.second);
```

---

If the types are different you'd have to write a small utility function for it, since there's no built-in way to do that, e.g.:

[godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/nrKqz6Ycb)

```cpp
template<class T>
constexpr auto pair_swap(T&& pair) {
    return std::make_pair(
        std::forward<T>(pair).second,
        std::forward<T>(pair).first
    );
}

// Usage Example:
std::pair p = {std::string{"A"}, 12};
auto p2 = pair_swap(std::move(p));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also swap the content directly

```cpp
std::pair el_ids(0,1);
std::swap(el_ids.first,el_ids.second);
```

Comment: Thank you this also works and solves the issue

Answer (score 1):

You can also use uniform initialization:

```
int main() {
  std::pair el_ids(0,1);
  el_ids = {el_ids.second, el_ids.first};
}
```

Running example: https://godbolt.org/z/6vjf58co8

Comment: Thank you as well , this works well.